# Has node.js problems with Albert Einstein?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

(the server adds a new user in a table using node.js and Express and MySQL)

Client:

```
...
console.log(options.path);
var request = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.toString());
  });   
});
request.end();  
request.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('ERROR:' + err.message + ', code: ' + err.code);
}); 
...
```

First test OK:

```
$ node test
/{"funcion":{"tabla":"usuarios","accion":"alta","ambito":"todos"},
             "dato":{"usuario_id":0,"nombre":"AlbertEinstein","dni":"00000000M",
             "usuario":"theory","password":"relativity","activo":0}}
{
  "fieldCount": 0,
  "affectedRows": 1,
  "insertId": 7,
  "serverStatus": 2,
  "warningCount": 0,
  "message": "",
  "protocol41": true,
  "changedRows": 0
}
```

Second test same as first but with a space between Albert and Einstein:

```
$ node test
/{"funcion":{"tabla":"usuarios","accion":"alta","ambito":"todos"},
             "dato": {"usuario_id":0,"nombre":"Albert Einstein","dni":"00000000M",
             "usuario":"theory","password":"relativity","activo":0}}
ERROR:socket hang up, code: ECONNRESET
```

"ERROR:socket hang up, code: ECONNRESET" when I send "**Albert Einstein**" works fine with "**AlbertEinstein**" !!!!!

Comment: If the connection is being reset, then it is probably an issue with the server logic, so what is your server code?

Comment: swap the values. What happend?

Comment: Can you post your mysql table structure and also the server code handling it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

Yes, it hates Albert Einstein but loves Albert%20Einstein !

```
Client
...
options.path = encodeURI(path);
...

Server
...
valor = decodeURI(request.params.valor);
...
```

A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.

Albert Einstein (or Albert%20Einstein)